# Parsing snmp walk output using python

Tags: python, snmp, jython-2.7

Can anyone suggest a good library or a method to parse the output similar to the following snmpwalk output.

The output is from a juniper box. I want to be able to extract things like the serial numbers and associate with the relevant components

[The full output can be viewed here.](https://ippacket.com.au/show-snmp-mib-walk-jnxboxanatomy-1-3-6-1-4-1-2636-3-1/)

```
SOME_DEVICE_NAME,2636.3.1.1.0 : OBJECT IDENTIFIER: .iso.org.dod.internet.private.enterprises.2636.1.1.1.1.40.0
SOME_DEVICE_NAME,2636.3.1.2.0 : OCTET STRING- (ascii):     node1 Juniper SRX650 Internet Router
SOME_DEVICE_NAME,2636.3.1.3.0 : OCTET STRING- (ascii):     AJ5113AK0055
SOME_DEVICE_NAME,2636.3.1.4.0 : OCTET STRING- (ascii):
SOME_DEVICE_NAME,2636.3.1.5.0 : Timeticks: (2147483647) 248 days, 13:13:56.47
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use some Python SNMP library to ease parsing the output.

You can use e.g. [Net-SNMP Python Bindings](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Python_Bindings). See [docs](https://github.com/haad/net-snmp/tree/master/python) for details.

Simplified example of usage:

```
import netsnmp

session = netsnmp.Session(DestHost="SOME_DEVICE_NAME", Version=2, Community="public")
session.UseLongNames = 1
session.UseNumeric = 1
oid=".1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.1"
vars = netsnmp.VarList(oid)
session.walk(vars)

# to check errors: if len(session.ErrorStr) > 0:

# to get output values
for item in vars:
        print item.val
```

Then you can use some regex parsing etc.